# Single click breakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I know I can set breakpoint in Eclipse via double click, but is there any way I can change it to single click instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the double-click behavior is set within code and not a preference. You can, however, right-click in the same area and toggle breakpoints from the menu that pops up.

Comment: crappy behavior - this needs to be a user preference not a product opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard short cut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.